# Formula field: Does current time zone have DST?

Tags: formula-field, timezone

I've tossed together some creative formula fields for a client who has some special requirements around Canadian time zones. They have a number of sites at which they need to book appointments, and call centers needs to be able to see the booking records and determine the time of the booking **in the time zone of the site itself, not their own**.

Here's the tricky thing - some of the users of this system (but not others) and some of the sites (but not others) are in a Canadian time zone that does not obey Daylight Savings Time.

What I'm wondering if there's any sort of creative formula field I can come up with that ends up checked if the user's running time zone uses DST (ever, regardless of whether it's DST right now)? So if the user is logged in with the Saskatchewan time zone it would be unchecked but for most other places in the country it would be checked.

If I can't figure this out I suppose I can also resort to asking the staff to just tick a box for all the users in SK.